# Yii2 trouble with Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

**Hello everybody! Please help me to solve the problem.**
I have some html

```
<ul class="filter_list filter_house_type">
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="House" onclick="sendRequest();"><label for="check1"><?= Yii::t('app', 'House') ?></label></li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
function sendRequest(){
   $.ajax({
       url: '/site/ajax',
       type: 'POST',
       data: { text: 'text' },
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
       }
   });
}
```

**Controller action**

```
public function actionAjax()
{
    if(Yii::$app->request->post('text')){
        $test = 'Ajax request';
    } else {
        $test = 'Some troubles!';
    }
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
}
```

**When I click on the checkbox i see a page with "Some troubles!" and console is empty.**
[image]
**Why rendering page? How can I get an answer in Ajax function. Please, help!**

Comment: This looks like you entered this `/ajax` url in browser and that is why you see what's there. When you click the checkbox on this html page you should see alert with `Ajax request`.

Comment: @Bizley 
Tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? What is broken here?

Comment: @Bizley I get an error {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":302,"statusText":"Moved Temporarily"}

Comment: 302 means you have been redirected. Your question needs some improvement - write how and what you are sending, what you expect and what you got instead.

Comment: @Bizley I want to understand how work with Ajax in Yii Framework. I click on ckeckbox and I want to send some text (for example: text:'text') in controller. After that I want to receive a variable from controller. But this Controller Action redirect me to page.

Comment: Like I said - it should work unless you've got some custom host settings. I'm not sure why you entered this ajax response page and asking why it's rendering this text.

Answer (score 1):

could be you need a check on post('text') eg:

```
  public function actionAjax()
  {
      $post = Yii::$app->request->post()
      if(isset($post('text')){
          $test = 'Ajax request';
      } else {
          $test = 'Some troubles!';
      }
      return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
  }
```

and try using method POST  instead  of type

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/site/ajax',
   method: 'POST',
   data: { text: 'text' },
   success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
   }
```

});

and just for debugging purpose try using a differente approach

use post instead of ajax ,.. test instead of text

```
$.post( '/site/ajax' , {test:'test'},
    function (data) { 
        alert(data);
 });
```

.

```
public function actionAjax()
{
    if(Yii::$app->request->post('test')){
        $test = 'Ajax request';
    } else {
        $test = 'Some troubles!';
    }
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your code, but it did not help

Comment: try  var_dump($post('text')) please and let me know

Comment: I added method instead type and use var_dump() in controller. The result: NULL "Some troubles!"

Comment: also in ajax function I added error: function (exception) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(exception));
        } and get this error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":302,"statusText":"Moved Temporarily"}

Comment: But i did not use redirect in controller.

Comment: I have update the answer with some suggestion let me know

Comment: I use post instead of ajax and change 'text' on 'test' and I still see empty page with "Some troubles!"

Comment: you have and index action in your site controller ? you have an htacces  or route configuretion somewhere ???

Comment: It seems I found the problem! I used multilanguage and in my config file urlManager :        ` 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'class' => 'frontend\widgets\MultiLang\components\UrlManager',
            'languages' => ['ru', 'en', 'ua'],
            'enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode' => true,
//            'suffix' => '.html',
            'rules' => [],
        ]`

When I comment 'class', 'languages' and 'enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode' Ajax request working and i get success: alert(data) withiut refreshing page

Comment: In ajax request i used url: "<?= Url::to(['/site/index']) ?>", to save my multilanguage. But in response a get a 403 error ('Forbidden'). How can i fix this?

Comment: url::to is an helpers for URL .. 403  seems that you have not the right permission for access to the action (or the file)  .. have you some limitation for access your dir ?

Comment: No, I do not have any restrictions

Comment: update you question and add the site actionIndex code please